# Input Autocompletable Php AJAX se muestra atrás del formulario

Tags: php, html, ajax

Ok, les cuento. 
Buenos días antes que nada. 
Tengo un formulario en html donde utilizo la clase "Modal".
vinculé la BD con PHP para el input autocomplementable. 
De eso no tengo problema. 
Mando a llamar los datos con el siguiente codigo:

```
 <td>Nombre profesor: </td>
   <td><input name="nombrePro" id="nombrePro" maxlength="100"></td>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       var items = <?= json_encode($array) ?>
       $("#nombrePro").autocomplete({
                        source: items
                          }); 
                      });
   </script>
```

La cuestion es que al momento de ejecutar en el servidor local, mi formulario aparece normal y escribo una letra pero las opciones aparecen detrás. 
no sé si me explico. ^^ 
Espero que me puedan ayudar o si tienen un ejemplo similar les agradecería.
Saludos.
Ejemplo_ 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tienes dos opciones basadas en el mismo atributo.

**Uno**:  Aumenta el atributo de estilo ***"z-index"*** al input, en 100 (por si las dudas) por ejemplo:

```
<input name="nombrePro" id="nombrePro" maxlength="100" style="z-index:100;"></td>
```

**Dos:** añade este estilo en la etiqueta  para aumentar el ***z-index*** del contenedor del autocomplete

```
.ui-autocomplete { position: absolute; cursor: default;z-index:30 !important;}
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda!

Comment: Lo intenté pero me hace el input más grande y me lo pone en la parte superior de mi formulario, además sigue apareciendo por detrás las opciones del autocompletado. Intenté con otras clases del ui del jquery, pero no da. Buscaré más opciones, aún así gracias compañero. Saludos.